# Wordpress file browser

Tags: images

I see plugins that somehow hook into the Wordpress file browser (so that users can either upload an image to the image library or choose an image from the image library) but I've been searching through the codex and can't seem to find a simple way to do this.

I'd like to add the image browser/file upload to my options page...

Comment: If you see plugins doing this then best way to find out how to do it would be to look at the plugin source code. The codex is lacking in a lot of information and I doubt you would find how to make an image uploader for your options page there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this article: [Using the WordPress Uploader in Your Plugin or Theme](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/01/08/using-the-wordpress-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/). I've successfully used this method to integrate the WP uploader with my own plugin.

Answer (score -1):

I've used: http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box-script-for-wordpress/ to create an upload images metabox....

Answer (score -1):

At the bottom of the article linked to by Devin, there is a link to a new article by the same guy, which shows the code updated to use the new media loader in WP 3.5:

http://www.webmaster-source.com/2013/02/06/using-the-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/

Comment: Please do not answer with link only answers. Everything needed to understand the answer should be part of the answer. Thanks. Also you better care about newer questions.